# Manually add a printer to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, printer, network-printer, windows-10-v1903

In the Windows 10 printers & scanners dialog, if you click "Add printer" and wait for a while, you will eventually see "The printer that I want isn't listed".  If you click that, it launches a more traditional windows form with a printer setup wizard.

Is there a shortcut I can manually launch to get this dialog directly?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command should get you directly to the dialog:

```
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\rundll32.exe" printui.dll,PrintUIEntryDPIAware /im
```

I remark that "The printer that I want isn't listed" is already visible
and clickable while "Add printer" is still churning.

Comment: This does not do what I want.  The command you listed opens the same dialog as `control printers`.

Comment: ahh, the `/im` switch is what I wanted.

Comment: Docs:  
   /il install printer using add printer wizard
   /im install printer using add printer wizard skiping network listed printers

Comment: /im is definitely what I want.

Comment: Hmmm... both work well enough for me, but I changed it in the answer.

Comment: @harrymc i tried both `/il`and `/im` and they are different screens, like OP said (Windows 10 1709)

Comment: I'm on 1903, but the difference is whether that dialog is all alone or before the Add Printer. The focus is always on the one you want. I haven't tried to see which one is better.